# ag-grid auto size columns and grid width

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using aggrid, I hope the column width is dynamic according to the content of the grid. I do it by using:

```js
params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();
```

But the width of the list is always slightly larger than the width of the content. For example, the width of my content is 50px, the width of the list after calling autoSizeAllColumns() is 70px, and the 20px on the right side of the list will be blank.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWkvb.png)

I want to delete this 20px blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the default CSS, which might get you your desired results, this is not perfect, but feel free to modify the CSS.

```
.ag-cell, .ag-full-width-row .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.ag-header-cell, .ag-header-group-cell {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SZsfiINLAhMhqGHl)